# Como puedo implementar temporizador simple.timer.js de jquery a mi pagina?

Tags: jquery-plugins

Estoy tratando de implementar temporizador regresivo a  un juego con el plugin simple.timer.js pero no me funciona. Lo que requiero es que dar click en el button del juego el contador que inicia en 02:00 funcione de manera regresiva.

```
 <div class="time">
    <h2 class="data-titulo">Tiempo</h2>
    <div class="timer" data-seconds-left=65></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn-reinicio" id="reinicio">Iniciar</button>
  </div>
```

He encontrado es ayuda de ejemplo en el link https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-jQuery.html pero al colocar $('.timer').startTimer(); no hace nada y me muestra un error por consola indicando que  $(...).startTimer is not a function, esto es lo que tengo por el momento en el js  para tratar de implementar el plugin en mi proyecto.

```
$('.btn-reinicio').click(function() {
     uno = document.getElementById('reinicio');
    if (uno.innerHTML == 'Iniciar') 
        uno.innerHTML = 'Reiniciar';
        $('.timer').startTimer();
});
```

Agradezco cualquier orientación o ayuda que me puedan brindar. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que referenciar también el plugin del jquery.simple.timer.js depues del de JQuery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/caike/jQuery-Simple-Timer/master/jquery.simple.timer.js"></script>
```

te dejo una demo

[simple.timer.js](https://jsfiddle.net/tL7a1knq/1/)